# Questions About Hashmaps and 2D Grids

Tags: java, grid, hashmap, 2d, libgdx

I'm working with a very large grid-based world that has around 50-90% of its grid spaces empty at any given time, therefore I chose to use a HashMap over an array.

The problem is that basic interactions don't seem to be working right, and I think it's because of some disconnect between the position the hashmap is using as a key and position as the grid object knows it.

These are the problems I'm having:

- object's ability to detect its neighbors is unreliable
- object deletion is unreliable

Here is the code:

The `getNeighbors` method of `GridObject`:

```
public ArrayList<GridObject> getNeighbors()
{
  ArrayList<GridObject> neighbors = new ArrayList<GridObject>(8);
  final int[] d = {-1, 0, 1};
  for(int i : d)
    for(int j : d)
      if(j != 0 || i != 0) // Don't use (0, 0)
      {        // Manager is just a wrapper for the HashMap; treat this like HashMap.get()
        GridObject p = manager.get(location.x + i, location.y + j);
    if(p != null) neighbors.add(p);
      }
  return neighbors;
}
```

This is from the update method of the `Manager` class. `MarkedForRemoval` is a `java.util.Stack` of Points that is populated by `GridObject` s that call `Manager.markForRemoval()`, which just pushes a passed point into the stack. `update()` runs once a frame:

```
public void update()
{
    // libgdx graphics stuff
    renderTarget.setColor(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f));
    renderTarget.fill();

    for(GridObject p : map.values())
    {
      renderTarget.drawPixel(p.location.x, p.location.y, Color.rgba8888(p.team.getColor()));
      p.update();
    }
    while(!markedForRemoval.isEmpty())
      map.remove(markedForRemoval.pop());
    }
```

And this is the `Manager.put()` method, which is the only way that new GridObjects are added:

```
public GridObject put(int x, int y)
{
  final Point p = new Point(x, y);
  return map.put(p, new GridObject(this, p));
}
```

And finally the `Manager.get()` method:

```
public GridObject get(int x, int y)
{
  return get(new Point(x, y));
}
```

I am using java.awt.Point to store the locations, which has both Objects.equals() and Object.hashCode() implemented correctly, as far as I know.

I am lost as to where I have gone wrong.

Comment: What are the keys and values in your map? Can you add some code snips?

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Condense your problem into the smallest possible piece of code which demonstrates the odd behavior and post that.

Comment: Added code snippets. Not compilable though, sorry.

Comment: what does `Manager.get()` look like?

Comment: Make sure that Points are never modified while they are being used as hashtable keys.

Comment: The comment "don't worry about the `manager.get()` method" is a big concern. I suspect that is where the problem lies, because if it doesn't work, the rest of the code doesn't matter. Please post the code for `manager.get()`.

Comment: @orzechowskid @Bohemian Added `Manager.get`. @Keith Why is this? I had a feeling that this would cause issues.

Comment: Is `Point` *your* class? If so, show its code. Otherwise, tell us which package it's from (I think we're getting close to the answer)

Comment: I said in the question: it's java.awt.Point, which (I sure hope) has Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() implemented correctly.